# put method not called in Stream.map

Tags: java, java-stream, mapping

I have a code below which is not working as expected so I would need a little help here. I have a `Set<Confirmation> confirmationSet` , `List<Import> importsList`, `Map<String, Verification> verificationMap` and a `Map<String, String> comprehensiveMap`.

What I want to achieve is:

1. Iterate through the Set of custom objects `(Set<Confirmation>) confirmationSet` using streams
2. In every iteration I want to **getConfirmationId()** from each Confirmation object which is a **String**
3. Based on **confirmationId** get `Verification` Object
4. From the given **Verification** object get `List<Import> importsList`
5. Iterate through `List<Import> importsList` using streams
6. Check if given import.getName() is already contained in the `comprehensiveMap`
7. If it's already present, throw an Exception.
8. If not present add to the map these properties`comprehensiveMap.put(import.getName(), confirmationId))`

What I've tried

```
confirmationSet.stream()
                 .map(Confirmation::getConfirmationId)
                 .map(confId-> verificationMap.get(confId))
                 .map(verifObj-> verifObj.getImportList())
                   .stream()
                     .peek(import -> Optional.of(testMap.containsKey(import.getName()))
                         .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException("Map already contains this key")))
                     .map(import -> comprehensiveMap.put(import.getName(), confirmationId)));
```

After running this code `comprehensiveMap` is empty.. What am I doing wrong?

My original code was:

```
confirmationSet.foreach(confirmation -> {

String confirmationId = confirmation.getConfirmationId();
Verification verification = verificationMap.get(confirmationId);
ImportList importList = verification.getImportList;
  importList.foreach(import -> {
    if(!testMap.containsKey(import.getName()){
       comprehensiveMap.put(import.getName(), confirmationId));
    } else {
      throw new CustomException("Map already contains this key")
   }
  }
});
```

But I wanted to make it more fancier..
Thanks

Comment: what is `testMap` in your question? `import` is a keyword, you cannot use it as a variable.  is there a class `ImportList` as well? without sharing the real problem, it's tough to find the real solution.

Answer (score 4):

`map` is not a terminal operation, it's for taking one object and turning it into another. If you want to modify something outside your passed function, you probably shouldn't use it. It's just because of the way Java Maps are designed that the `put` method returns an object, but this won't always be true. To actually run your function, you'd need to collect the Stream or do some other terminal operation.

Here's a list of terminal operations ([Source](https://www.java2novice.com/java_interview_questions/java-8-stream-terminal-operations/)):

- toArray()
- collect()
- count()
- reduce()
- forEach()
- forEachOrdered()
- min()
- max()
- anyMatch()
- allMatch()
- noneMatch()
- findAny()
- findFirst()

However, I think `map` is not what you want here. Since you want to go through the stream and perform an action for each element, you should use `forEach` instead, which fits best here. It will run the function that you give it right there. `forEach` takes a `Consumer`, so you're kinda supposed to give it "impure" functions that modify stuff outside, like the lambda you put in your `map`.

I'd also suggest composing those first few `map` calls into one, by the way.

EDIT: I think your code should look something like this now:

```
confirmationSet.stream()
  .map(Confirmation::getConfirmationId)
  .forEach(confId -> 
    verificationMap
      .get(confId)
      .getImportList()
      .stream()
      .forEach(impt -> {
        if (!comprehensiveMap.containsKey(impt))
          comprehensiveMap.put(impt);
        else throw new CustomException();
      })
  );
```

Comment: @MarkyMark You can still keep it fancy, just replace that last `map` with a `forEach` and the rest of your code can stay the same

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do that? I'm little bit confused

Comment: I've deleted the comment as code doesn't belong here and edited the question

Comment: @user Using peek is not a good idea, it's generally used for debugging purposes

Comment: @Eklavya Yeah, I've changed the OP's code quite a bit now, although I'm not sure if I interpreted it correctly